# Not understanding basic Bash variables and command grouping

Tags: bash, variables

Adding in comments to ask specific questions as I go:

Single or double quote marks when settings strings?

```
echo "Starting..."
```

Do I need to terminate the line with a `;`?

```
TARGET_DIR="~/Downloads"
```

I can't get the `$TARGET_DIR` to expand, tried quotes, preens with `$etc`, 
is there a canonical beginners guide to these types of issues that presents
them in the proper way, not the force it to work with back tics and multiple lines?

```
LAST_DOWNLOADED_FILE=$(ls -t $TARGET_DIR | head -n1)
echo "Your newest file in $TARGET_DIR is: $LAST_DOWNLOADED_FILE"
```

When run on Mac, I get:

```
ls: ~/Downloads: No such file or directory
Your newest file in ~/Downloads is:
```

Trying as a one liner:

```
me@compy $FOO="~/Downloads"; echo $(FOO); ls -t $FOO | head -n1
-bash: FOO: command not found
```

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html also `man command` provides useful information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
TARGET_DIR=~/Downloads
```

i.e. keep tilde `~/` outside quote, otherwise shell won't expand it and `~` will be treated literally.

Comment: +1. Note that `TARGET_DIR=~/"Downloads"` and `TARGET_DIR=~/'Downloads'` also work. (Not needed for this example, but useful if the stuff after the `~/` is more complicated.)

Comment: No, the whole `~/` part needs to be outside the quotes.

Comment: Yes I misspoke, you're right it should be `~/` outside quotes.

Comment: Thanks! What is the proper way to deal with variables that have spaces in their names, or may: echo "Your newest file in $SOME_FILE"; say that $SOME_FILE is 'this is a test'

Comment: @Scott: You can do `TARGETDIR=~/"$SOME_FILE"`

Answer (score 0):

`~` sign inside quotes is considered a literal by shell. You need to either keep it outside of quotes as [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22279148/970195) suggested in his answer or use `eval` to interpolate it.

```
$ TARGET_DIR="~/tmp"
$ echo $TARGET_DIR
~/tmp
$ eval echo $TARGET_DIR
/home/jaypalsingh/tmp
```

**Note:** Make sure you read all the **[pros and cons](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)** of `eval` before considering it as an option.